# How do I get correct substring using Regex

Tags: java, regex, json

How I can get `fr` and `en` from `["fr", "en"]` using regex?
I have tried to use `split("[\\W]+")` but it gives me 3 items (`""`, `"fr"` and `"en"`).

How can I do this without getting that first empty string, and just get `fr` and `en`?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=")[^",]+(?=")
```

Simply do a match instead of split.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/8

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `split` you should use this regex to match the desired parts:

```
(?<=")\w+(?=")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV2vG6/1)

In Java:

```
String str = "[\"fr\", \"en\"]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\")\\w+(?=\")");
Matcher = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

**Output:**

```
fr
en
```

Comment: i updated answer with complete Java code for your help.

Comment: any specific reason why you deleted your comment, so you don't deserve it

Comment: Sorry I didn't get, which comment I deleted?